# Drawing a function block

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to recreate something like this:

[image: what I'm trying to recreate]

However, as a LaTeX n00b I can't get my head around placing the text inside and the arrows on the bottom.

This is how far I have gotten:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going right,
    every join/.style={thick},
    node distance=5mm
]

\node [on chain] {Inngang};

\node [on chain,draw,join,xshift=5mm,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=3cm,label=above:Måleomformer] (omformer) {
  \tikz\draw (0,0) -- (5cm,3cm);
};

\node [on chain,join,xshift=5mm]{4-20 mA utgang};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: how far I've gotten]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why did you choose to build it in a chain? I see bar measurements and thousandths of an ampere, so what does that represent?

Comment: I was just trying to build on an example I found. I don't have any particular requirements to how to get to the end result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work. The diagonal and text inside the box has bee added with a `path picture` command, but they could also be added with additional `draw` and `node` commands. Instead of `chain` I've placed the main node, and all other around it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm
]

\node [draw, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=3cm, 
    label=Måleomformer, 
    path picture={%
        \draw (path picture bounding box.south west)--(path picture bounding box.north east);
        \path (path picture bounding box.north west)--node[pos=.25] {Trykk} node[pos=.75] {Strom} (path picture bounding box.south east) ;
}] (omformer) {};

\node[left=of omformer] (inngang) {Inngang};


\node[right=of omformer] (out) {4-20 mA utgang};

\node[below right=of omformer.south west, align=center] (zero) {Nedre\\ malegrense\\ (Zero)};

\node[below left=of omformer.south east, align=center] (span) {Ovre\\ malegrense\\ (Span)};

\draw[->] (inngang)--(omformer);
\draw[->] (zero)--(zero|-omformer.south);
\draw[->] (span)--(span|-omformer.south);
\draw[<-] (out)--(omformer);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)